# How to view the bean shell pre or post processor result

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use beanshell post processor so I have started with simple http request where I am hitting the google home page. "${url}"=="https://www.google.co.in". After http request page I am adding the BeanShellPostProcessor where in Script area I am using ctx variable and some other code which is like :

```
int threadNum = ctx.getThreadNum();
String code = prev.getResponseCode(); 
String message = prev.getResponseMessage();

log.info(threadNum);
log.info("This line has been written by Beanshell Post Processor");
```

so I have two concerns -

i.The way I am using beanshell is this right ?

ii.Where is the console for beanshell processor in jmeter?
like sample request result can be viewed in listener. I tried with BeanShellListner, but it doesn't show any data.
Also I have kept the "log viewer" on.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using it almost right, the only error is that you cannot write an integer to the log file, you need to cast it to [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) first like:

   ```
   log.info(String.valueOf(threadNum));
   ```
2. You won't be able to see the result of pre and post processors anywhere apart from *jmeter.log* file. In case of PostProcessor you can modify parent sampler response data via `prev.setResponseData()` method where `prev` is a shorthand to [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance

I would also recommend considering switching to [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language as this way you will get better performance, out of box support of XML, JSON, etc., and other Groovy's "syntax sugar". See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Drimiti : Thanks. 
In order to display the log in jemeter.log do I have to set any parameter or any kind of changes in jmeter set up ?

Comment: Nothing, `log.info("something");` will print `something` into *jmeter.log* file.

Comment: Also can you narrate in short what is real life example of using bean shell in jmeter for any performance / load testing project ? I am using everything on trail basis and which ever is suitable or rather useful is keeping in our scripts. Its like we are on more exploring side on jmeter.

Comment: You should be using scripting when your use case cannot be implemented using JMeter's test elements, normally you should avoid it